# hyperlink issue

Tags: hyperlink

I want to refer to the Theorem and corollary at different places with the same number. But it's not working, any idea of an alternative to this issue.
Thanking you in advance!

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    
    
Theorem \hyperlink{1}{3.5.1}
\pagebreak
    
    
Please refer Theorem \hyperlink{1}{3.5.1}

Corollary \hyperlink{1}{3.5.1}
\pagebreak


Please refer Corollary \hyperlink{1}{3.5.1}

%I want to refer Theorem and corollary with a same number.
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is not how one typically make theorems, one makes theorem environments, which are numbered and then one uses the normal `\label` and `\ref` system to refer to theorems etc. Then when `hyperref` is added these `\ref`'s are automatically made into hyperlinks. Making `Theorem 3.5.1` by hand is a waste of time.

Comment: As is pointed out by daleif, maybe you can have a look at package `amsthm`, which provides `theorem` environment by declaring `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}`.

Comment: Thank you sir @daleif